# How to make counter with custom images?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to make a "tally counter" like application in Xcode with my custom images only numeric digits 0-999 to looks like this:

[image]

And I don't know from where to start. I know how to do it with UILabel and system fonts, but i want to use my custom photoshop images without fonts or labels. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it pretty much as for websites (remembering the old good 90s when every website had a graphical visitor counter...)

Create an UIImageView that will be the background (bg.png), and one image for each digits (0.png ... 9.png). Now in interface builder you place four images over the background, initializing them say with 0.png. In your view controller, in turn, you can change the png loaded in the UIImageView, so if the UIImageView of your first digit is called digit1 and you want to set it to 6, you'd use

`digit1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", 6]];`

Comment: Yes, but i want a counter so every time button is tapped add +1 to the current value 0000  0001 0002 etc. Not just to set a image on some uiimageview.

Comment: From a number like 1234 you can get the digits 1, 2, 3, 4 with a very basic math by divisions and modulus. Try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Yup! MrTJ, perfect salutation .. +1 for you

Comment: I am glad that it was useful for +1 person